# Cannot solve Ax=b for A using python if there is no unique solution

Tags: python, linear-algebra, cvxpy, linear-equation

I am trying to solve a linear system of equations of the form `Ax=b` where `A` is a square matrix which is unknown, while the vectors `x` and `b` are known. I am interested in a physics problem where my `A` is a unitary matrix, which rotates a random unit vector `x` to `b` which is of the form [1,0,0...0]. One cannot find a unique solution to `A`. I just need one of the many possible solutions.
Since I want to scale it to larger dimensions, I want the computer to solve it.

I tried following the answer to the [question in this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1170843/solving-ax-b-when-x-and-b-are-given) , but by `A` was not unitary.

I am thinking of using cvxpy to give me a solution, and I wrote a code taking the dimension to be three for a start. I don't know if cvxpy is suitable when there is no unique solution. The code is below. It gives an error in the constraint part saying "*0-dimensional array given. Array must be at least two-dimensional*".  I think what I have is a valid representation of a matrix in cvxpy. I am happy to be corrected.

Can someone help me with this problem? If you have another way of doing it, that is also fine.

```
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cp
n = 3
alpha=0.01
np.random.seed(1)
b= [1,0,0]
x = np.random.randn(n)+1j*np.random.randn(n)
x=x/np.linalg.norm(x)


#Construct the problem.
A = cp.Variable((n,n),complex=True)
objective = cp.Minimize(cp.sum_squares(A @ x - b))
constraints = [A.H==np.linalg.inv(A)]
prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)

# The optimal objective value is returned by `prob.solve()`.
result = prob.solve()
print(A.value)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/sreerampg/untitled1.py", line 22, in <module>     constraints = [A.H==np.linalg.inv(A)]
    File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in inv    File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 539, in inv     _assert_stacked_2d(a)
    File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 197, in _assert_stacked_2d     
    'at least two-dimensional' % a.ndim)  LinAlgError: 0-dimensional array given. Array must be at least two-dimensional
```

Comment: Have you considered the scipy module and specifically scipy.linalg?

Comment: Post the whole stacktrace

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/sreerampg/untitled1.py", line 22, in <module>
    constraints = [A.H==np.linalg.inv(A)]

  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in inv

  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 539, in inv
    _assert_stacked_2d(a)

  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 197, in _assert_stacked_2d
    'at least two-dimensional' % a.ndim)

LinAlgError: 0-dimensional array given. Array must be at least two-dimensional ` @julaine

Comment: @user19077881 scipy.linalg.solve solves for x given A and b. I couldn't find a command which would solve for A. If you know, please comment

Comment: @sreerampg it seems like a fine question with some research and code to me. Don't be put off by downvotes. It is just how the system works.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you could approach this analytically, since you're looking for a rotation. In 3 dimensions, you could directly construct the rotation matrix by computing the angle between `x` and `b`, and the vector perpendicular to both:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation

def find_rot(a, b):
    a /= np.linalg.norm(a)
    b /= np.linalg.norm(b)
    angle = np.arccos(np.dot(a, b))
    vec = np.cross(a, b)
    return Rotation.from_rotvec(vec * angle / np.linalg.norm(vec))

x = np.random.rand(3)
b = np.array([1., 0., 0.])
A = find_rot(x, b)
print(x, b, A.apply(x), A.as_matrix(), sep='\n')
```

In higher dimensions it's not as direct since you can't just use the cross product, although there's probably a way to generalize the above using exterior product for which I'd need to brush up on my linear algebra skills more.

Barring that, you can construct a series of "higher dimensional rotation matrices" that successively zero out each dimension, of the form:

```
[1 . . . . 
 . 1 
 .   1
 .     . 
 .       cosT -sinT
 .       sinT cosT]
```

Where T is the angle theta between your vector `x` and the unit vector `[0, 0, ...., 1, 0]`, then repeat moving down one dim at a time. Essentially you "rotate out" your vector from each dimension, then multiply them all together to get your final unitary matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You want `Ax = b`, where A is unitary, so this is equivalent to `A^* b = x`, where `A^*` is the complex transpose (Hermitian). Look for `A^*` instead. Since `b = [1,0,...]`, the vector b is the first unit vector, so you are looking for unitary matrices with `x` on the first column (and this determines the first row):

```
A^* = [x1, x2^*,...,xn^*|
       x2, ...
```

in other word, the solution is a matrix `A` with `x^*` (the complex conjugate of x) on the first column, the rest of the components of `x` on the first row, and a unitary matrix of size (n-1)x(n-1) filling the rest of the matrix.

(As you see, for this to have a solution, x1, the first component of `x` must be real)